# JPA Unit testing - Query returning more entities than were ever persisted

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, junit, openjpa

I have written a bunch of entities. I am trying to test them now. I was having problems with an entity very similar to this, but all of a sudden the problem went away when I cleaned the build. Then I started writing a similar test for SetMap, and then..... same problem. I am 99.9999% sure I am only perisisting 100 SetMaps. however, my test says there are 101 with the query in the code below.

1. I feel like these tests suck. Can someone give me some pointers on unit testing Entity classes? what exactly should I be testing for? merely existing after I persist them?
2. why, why, why are there 101 SetMaps returned in my test method below. How... why... =-[
3. I get this error everytime I compile:

   89  persistence-test  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - The persistence unit "persistence-test" was found multiple times in the following resources "[file:/home/matt/Code/vox/vox-lib/vox-lib-common/vox-entity/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml, file:/home/matt/Code/vox/vox-lib/vox-lib-common/vox-entity/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml]", but persistence unit names should be unique. The first persistence unit matching the provided name in "file:/home/matt/Code/vox/vox-lib/vox-lib-common/vox-entity/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" is being used.
   202  persistence-test  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.1.1
   448  persistence-test  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary".

there is definitely only one persistence.xml in my src/main/resources/META-INF folder.
I am using maven. Is it possible maven is copying something somewhere?

```
public class SetMapTest {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityTransaction tx;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-test");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManager() throws SQLException {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void initTransaction() {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {

        // check that nothing is there
        String s = "SELECT x FROM SetMap x";
        Query q = em.createQuery(s);
        List<SetMap> qr = q.getResultList();
        assertEquals(0, qr.size());



        int count = 100;
        // util method that returns setMaps where setMap.title = 'title:i'
        // where 0 <= i < count 
        ArrayList<SetMap> setMaps = TestUtil.getNumberedSetMapList(count);
        assertEquals(setMaps.size(), count);

        VoxUser author = TestUtil.getNumberedVoxUser(0);
        SetPatternMap setPatternMap = TestUtil.getNumberedSetPatternMap(0);
        setPatternMap.setAuthor(author);
        author.addSetPatternMap(setPatternMap);

        tx.begin();
        em.persist(author);
        em.persist(setPatternMap);

        Iterator<SetMap> iter = setMaps.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){


            SetMap setMap = iter.next();
            em.persist(setMap);
            setMap.setAuthor(author);
            author.addSetMap(setMap);
            setMap.setSetPatternMap(setPatternMap);
            setPatternMap.addSetMap(setMap);

        }
        tx.commit();

        String qString = "SELECT x FROM SetMap x";
        q = em.createQuery(qString);
        qr = q.getResultList();
        assertEquals(count, qr.size());  // this is the method that fails
        // it claims there are 101 SetMaps in the P.C.


        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            String qt = "SELECT x FROM SetMap x WHERE x.title = 'title:" + i + "'";
            q = em.createQuery(qt);
            qr = q.getResultList();
            assertEquals(1, qr.size());
            // i played around with this a little bit. It seems there are two SetMaps
            // whose titles are "title:0" I can't figure out how that is....
        }
    }
}
```

some of my util methods:

```
public static PhraseMap getNumberedPhraseMap(int pos){
        PhraseMap phraseMap = new PhraseMap();
        phraseMap.setTitle("title:" + pos);
        return phraseMap;
 }

public static ArrayList<PhraseMap> getNumberedPhraseMapList(int count){
        ArrayList<PhraseMap> phraseMaps = new ArrayList<PhraseMap>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            PhraseMap phraseMap = getNumberedPhraseMap(i);
            phraseMaps.add(phraseMap);
        }
        return phraseMaps;
}
```

help please!

Comment: Have you included all @Test methods? So there aren't more tests interfering with `testSomeMethod`. What happens if you set count to 1? Do you end up with two entities?

Comment: The testSomeMethod() is the only test method in SetMapTest, however there are some other test classes testing other entities. I am under the impression that these other test classes operate on a completely seperate data base instance, so isn't it impossible that another test class be interfering? Is this correct? Even so, no other class creates the extra SetMap. Also, if i set count to 1, there are two SetMap entities created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is definitely only one persistence.xml in my
>   src/main/resources/META-INF folder

Who said there wasn't ? Maven says there is one in 
*/home/matt/Code/vox/vox-lib/vox-lib-common/vox-entity/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml*

and one in
*/home/matt/Code/vox/vox-lib/vox-lib-common/vox-entity/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml*

and both of these are in the CLASSPATH at **runtime** (you are not compiling at that point, maybe "compile" was one of the goals invoked but this is not in that step).
So fix your *pom.xml* to not copy things around when Maven is doing some things for you. That would (should) then remove the error message